# Efficient implemention of operator[] for custom N-d arrays in c++ (using variadic template)

Tags: templates, c++17, variadic-templates

First I would like to say that I do this to learn about variadic templates and that I am aware of libraries such as boost or xTensor that already implement N-d arrays.

As the title says, I would like to implement operator[](size_t i) such that it returns a (N-1)-d array which is a slice of the original array at index i.

Here is the relevant part of the code (C++17):

```
template <size_t firstDim, size_t... RestDims>
class Array
{
private:

    static constexpr size_t N = sizeof...(RestDims) + 1;
    static constexpr size_t length = firstDim*(RestDims * ...);
    static constexpr size_t Dims[] = {firstDim, RestDims...};

    double* data_;

public:

    // Base constructor
    Array() {
        data_ = new double[length];
        std::fill_n(data_,length, 0.0);
    }

    // copy constructor
    Array(Array<firstDim, RestDims...> const& other) {
        data_ = new double[length];
        std::copy(other.data_, other.data_ + length, data_);
    }
    
    ~Array() {
        delete data_;
    }
};


// specialization for N=1

// ...
```

My first idea was to add a sub-array of type Array<RestDims...> which would be defined recursively down to a 1-d array (hence the need for a specialization of 1-d arrays). The operator[] simply moves the sub-array's pointer and returns a reference to it. This is quite efficient and works fine unless I use operator[] more than once in the same expression (both sub-arrays point to the same data since operator[] returns a reference).

My second idea was to have an array of pointers to sub-arrays and dynamically allocate sub-arrays in operator[] the first time it is used and then reuse it if the sub-array is accessed again. This solves the previous issue but it is inefficient since it is essentially the same as using nested vectors (and I do get similar performance).

Is there a way to be (almost) as efficient as the first implementation while solving the mentioned issue?

Comment: There are three things you should know before trying to do this. (1) Don't do this. (2) No, seriously. It makes no sense. (3) Just say no to this idea. Write `operator()` with whatever number of arguments you need. Five minutes, you are done. No bugs that haunt you for years to come, no performance issues, no SO questions. Bam! Ticket closed, done, it Just Works™, move on. Nobody cares about syntax.

Comment: I already implemented the operator() which works as expected, though I didn't show it's definition since it is not relevant for the question. I would like to use the sub-array for separate operations.

Comment: Define separate operations, and don't call them `operator[]` (until c++23 which will get multi-argument `operator[]`).